# How to order by modified (desc) and remove duplicate results in SPO List Datatable

Tags: sharepoint-online, odata, datatable

Below is a working datatable for my SPO list called **Companies**. There are some duplicates in this list, but I want all of the duplicates removed. I have attempted the solutions on the DT site, but nothing seems to work.Below is a simple datatable with one calculated column (text) called **calcCompanyRecent**. Full script is below. Thanks in advance!

---

```
<!—Data tables CSS -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/> 
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/> 
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css"/>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css"/> 

<!—Data tables JS -->
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../../SiteAssets/solutions/datatable-editor/dataTables.altEditor.free.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        // Datatable Script

        $(document).ready(function() {  
            loadMyItems();  
        });  

        function loadMyItems() {  
            var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;  
            var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Companies')/items?$select=calcCompanyRecent,Modified&$orderby=Modified desc&$top=20";  
            $.ajax({  

                url: oDataUrl,  
                type: "GET",  
                dataType: "json",  
                headers: {  
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
                },  
                success: mySuccHandler,  
                error: myErrHandler  
            });  
        }  

        function mySuccHandler(data) {  
            try {  
                var dataTableExample = $('#table_id').DataTable();  
                if (dataTableExample != 'undefined') {  
                    dataTableExample.destroy();  
                }  
                dataTableExample = $('#table_id').DataTable({  
                    scrollY: 200,
                    responsive: true,  
                    "aaSorting": [[1,'desc']],  
                    "aaData": data.d.results,  
                        "iDisplayLength": 5,
                    "aoColumns": [
                    {     
                        "mData": "calcCompanyRecent"  
                    }]  
                });  
            } 
        catch (e) {  
                alert(e.message);  
            }  
        }  

        function myErrHandler(data, errCode, errMessage) {  
            alert("Error: " + errMessage);  
        }  

        // Invoke CompanyList NewForm Modal

        function openCoListModal() {
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
                width: 800,
                height: 500,
                        url: "/Lists/companylist/AddNew.aspx"
            });
        }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">  

            // Using the DialogOptions class  
            function OpenDialog(strPageURL) {  
                var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();  
                dialogOptions.url = strPageURL; // URL of the Page  
                // Width of the Dialog  
                dialogOptions.width = 800;  
                // Height of the Dialog  
                dialogOptions.height = 530;  
                // Function to capture dialog closed event  
                //dialogReturnValueCallback - A function pointer that specifies the return callback function. The function takes two parameters, a dialogResult of type SP.UI.DialogResult Enumeration and a returnValue of type object that contains any data returned by the dialog.  
                dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);  
                // Open the Dialog  
                SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions);  
                return false;  
            }  

            // Dialog close event capture function  
            function CloseCallback(strReturnValue, target) {  
                location.reload(true);  
            }
          var columnDefs = [{
            title: "Title"
          }, {
            title: "calcCompanyRecent"
          }];

            var myTable;
          myTable = $('#table_id').DataTable({
            sPaginationType: 'none',
            data: 'data.d.results', 
                                        dom: 'Bfrtip',        // Needs button container
                  select: 'single',
                  responsive: 'true',

                  altEditor: 'true',     // Enable altEditor
                  buttons: [{
                    text: 'Add',
                    name: 'add'        // do not change name
                  },
                  {
                    extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                    text: 'Edit',
                    name: 'edit'        // do not change name
                  },
                  {
                    extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                    text: 'Delete',
                    name: 'delete'      // do not change name
                 }]
          });


        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Which column is your unique column which will be used to remove duplicates?

Comment: I don't have one. What kind of column does it need to be?

Comment: Column from which you identify that this is a duplicate record.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking if it was a text column, calculated column, etc. Once it's created, how do I include it into a solution?

Comment: Can you share schema of your list and how you are try identifying a duplicate entries?

Comment: What does it mean to share a schema?

Answer (score 0):

So you have the results ordered by `Modified` but want also to remove duplicates. I can see that you are selecting two properties `calcCompanyRecent` and `Modified` so 
 `calcCompanyRecent` could be used as a unique key to filter out duplicates. Update your function `mySuccHandler` with following code:

```
function mySuccHandler(data) {
    try {
        var dataTableExample = $('#table_id').DataTable();
        if (dataTableExample != 'undefined') {
            dataTableExample.destroy();
        }

        const uniqueCustomers = [...new Set(data.d.results.map(x => x.calcCompanyRecent))];
        const uniqueResults = uniqueCustomers.map(c => {
            return {
                calcCompanyRecent: c,
                Modified: array.find(y => y.calcCompanyRecent === c).Modified
            };
        });

        dataTableExample = $('#table_id').DataTable({
            scrollY: 200,
            responsive: true,
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'desc']],
            "aaData": uniqueResults,
            "iDisplayLength": 5,
            "aoColumns": [{
                "mData": "calcCompanyRecent"
            }]
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

As you can see it will create new variable called `uniqueResults` from fetched data which is then used in `DataTable > aaData`.

> Reference
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Thanks for this, but when I tried it, it didn't work.I just swapped out your function (above) with mine in the original code. No dice. Any ideas?

Comment: @TheJDScott What browser are you using? Use F12 console to debug.

Comment: @TheJDScott You are right that it was not what you needed. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working. How about we get rid of the 'Modified' column entirely and instead just have a single column 'calcCompanyRecent' be the ONLY column in this data table. Will that make thius easier to accomplish?

Comment: What is not working? Some error (F12>Console)? Or it just does not do what you expect?

Comment: Use console.log(uniqueResults) to see if it is correct array to use with DataTable aaData.